# What activation function or pre-processing to use for features describing when a certain event occurred in the past?

Tags: regression, data-preprocessing, activation-function

I have a series of features that describe how long ago a certain event happened and whether it happened at all.

Of course we could break down this features into two, whether it did happen or no, and how long ago did it happen with discrete values.

Or better yet, when event did not happen, set the feature to 0, otherwise set the features as a count how many minutes ago did the event happen.

So if an event happened 5 minutes ago, we will pass a value of 5, if it did not happen, then 0, etc. to our training loop.

However there is a huge problem with this approach when using a linear regression method because the values we have above are not in a linear order.

In fact, probably the most impact would be expected from an event happened just now (i.e. 1 min ago), and then probably degrades as it goes over 10 or more. And 0 is very close to 1 so since our features is non linear we can't just pass into into a training loop.

We could also define an event that never occurred as some very large number, i.e. 10^6 but then again, the values 1 to 10 would be so far apart from 10^6 that it would make virtually no difference among the former.

Using knowledge of math and calculus we could of course design our own custom function that would return 1 when the occurrence of event is just now (i.e. 1 min ago) and then gradually make the returning value decline.

Example: $\frac{1}{x}$ when x>=1 and 0 when the event not occurred.

The only problem is, I have no clue when the event starts losing impact.

Could be 2 mins, could be 100 when the impact starts declining.

So if I use the above 1/x function I could be chopping my output to virtually zero for when the values are large but could still have an impact.

If I make it more sensitive I could be potentially be giving a lot of weight to events that no longer have any impact.

Because I have dozens of different types of events, each event class will have its own non-linear, unknown relationship between time passed and the impact of that event.

So, what could be the solution here in order to maximize the accuracy of my predictions?

Comment: I'm thinking, we could potentially divide intervals of time series into sub intervals example: divine 1 day into 24 hours and pass true false values all event types multiplied by 24 whether an event occurred or not. But the problem is that it will result in too many features and non-sensical weight distribution, favoring particular hours way more than adjacent hours, i.e. essentially overfitting.

Comment: This is not verty clear! Please tell us about your specific application, sample sizes, ...  But regression for events, look into logistic regression (search this site)